# ¿Se escribe punto tras los paréntesis de una elipsis que no lleva nada detrás?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Hace un momento he escrito una pregunta en la cual, al ir a hacer una elipsis de la parte final de un texto, me ha surgido la duda de qué hacer con el punto final.

Como estoy inspirado, en vez de usar el texto de la pregunta original, voy a poner otro ejemplo:

> Al sur, gris plomizo. Al norte, un cada vez más tímido azul. La batalla de los colores en el cielo no era en absoluto reflejo de la monumental monotonía que Luis experimentaba a ras de tierra, aburrido en un mar de naves industriales salpicado aquí y allá por espejos con forma de edificio de ocho plantas.

Este texto es, para mí, relativamente largo para lo que considero una pregunta eficaz. Supongamos que lo quiero acortar así:

> La batalla de los colores en el cielo no era en absoluto reflejo de la monumental monotonía que Luis sufría a ras de tierra, aburrido en un mar de naves industriales (...)

Y aquí mi duda: ¿es eso correcto? ¿O es necesario poner el punto final tras el último paréntesis, así?

> La batalla de los colores en el cielo no era en absoluto reflejo de la monumental monotonía que Luis sufría a ras de tierra, aburrido en un mar de naves industriales (...).

Reconozco que me puede estar influenciando el hecho de que *no* se pone punto final tras los puntos suspensivos normales...

Comment: No sé en español, pero en inglés para indicar supresión, se usan corchetes: [...] // Alguien me dio una respuesta súper útil hace poco en ELU, espero que te ayude también.  Básicamente dice que pocas veces se necesita realmente la elipsis: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/432552/112436

Comment: pregunta ! ? que significa la elipsis entre parentesis ?

Comment: @Erin - Creo que se trata de citar un texto, pero con una omisión.  Por ejemplo: "Padre nuestro, [...] Venga tu reino."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT) se habla sobre el punto combinado con paréntesis:

> El punto se escribirá siempre detrás de las comillas, los paréntesis y
>   las rayas de cierre: *Dijo: «Tú y yo hemos terminado». Tras estas
>   palabras se marchó, dando un portazo. (Creo que estaba muy enfadada).
>   En la calle la esperaba Emilio —un buen amigo—. Este, al verla llegar,
>   sonrió.*

<s>Como nada dice lo contrario y la elipsis usando «(...)» no es un signo en sí mismo sino una combinación de paréntesis y puntos suspensivos entiendo que debe ponerse punto si está al final de una frase.</s>

En la [Ortografía de la lengua española (2010)](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=huolRkTizFjkCwPU) se trata el tema más específicamente hablando de puntos suspensivos entre paréntesis o corchetes:

> El resultado de la intervención no debe alterar la puntuación original
>   del texto, ya que la cita ha de tener continuidad lógica, gramatical y
>   ortográfica. Por tanto, cuando la marca de supresión coincida con
>   signos de puntuación, se conservarán los necesarios para que el
>   fragmento resultante siga siendo correcto.

Después de unos ejemplos también dice que no es necesario poner la elipsis al principio o al final y si se hace se usan puntos suspensivos sin paréntesis ni corchetes:

> No es necesario marcar la supresión de texto al comienzo o al  final.
>   No obstante, si se quiere dejar claro que la reproducción de  una cita
>   textual no se hace desde el principio mismo del enunciado, es
>   posible escribir puntos suspensivos al inicio de la cita, sin 
>   paréntesis ni corchetes, dejando un blanco de separación respecto de
>   la palabra a la que preceden: (...) Asimismo, cuando la reproducción de la cita queda incompleta por su parte final, es posible escribir puntos suspensivos, sin paréntesis ni corchetes y sin blanco de separación con respecto al texto que antecede, para indicar que el enunciado continúa más
>   allá de la última palabra reproducida.

Comment: Ahora la pregunta es: ¿Cómo sabemos si los puntos suspensivos pertenecen al texto citado o es quemos marcar la supresión? Porque puede darse el caso que el texto termine con puntos suspensivos aunque no sea lo más habitual.