# ¿Se puede no puntuar un texto entre paréntesis?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Si tengo un texto con la forma:

> Él está ahí. (Yo estoy acá)

¿Es sintácticamente correcto?

Comment: Curioso, pensaba que esto ya había sido preguntado. Veo información útil en [¿Se escribe punto tras los paréntesis de una elipsis que no lleva nada detrás?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24478/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui Lo vi pero pensé que era un caso especifico de paréntesis que están en el texto, no "aparte".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas aclara esto en su artículo sobre el [punto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT):

> 3. Combinación con otros signos
>
> 3.1. El punto se escribirá siempre detrás de las comillas, los paréntesis y las rayas de cierre: *Dijo: «Tú y yo hemos terminado». Tras estas palabras se marchó, dando un portazo. (Creo que estaba muy enfadada). En la calle la esperaba Emilio —un buen amigo—. Este, al verla llegar, sonrió.*

Lo mismo documenta en [*paréntesis*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XFiqsCjr2D68AoepU2):

> 3. c) Independientemente de que el texto entre paréntesis abarque todo el enunciado o solo parte de este, el punto se colocará siempre detrás del paréntesis de cierre (→ [punto, 3.1](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT)): *Se fue dando un portazo. (Creo que estaba muy enfadado).*

Por tanto, en tu caso lo correcto sería:

> Él está ahí. (Yo estoy acá).
>                                           ^

Comment: elimino mi respuesta por que esta tiene contenido mas útil y relevante +1